# Git flow - get rid of a particular feature

Tags: git, branch, release, git-flow

I'm currently trying to set up a development process in my team and read about GitFlow. It looks interesting, but I can spot a few issues.

Let's assume the following scenario:

We finish features `F1`, `F2` and `F3`, and merge these into the `develop` branch. Based on this we create a `release` branch.

What could we do if we want to get rid of feature `F3`?

Take a look at this image to get a better idea.

[image]

Comment: What would cause you to cut a feature from the release?  In theory by the time it makes it into `develop` it's been tested and ready to go (essentially inventory).

Comment: @R0MANARMY As I see it, there could be quite a number of reasons. The client refuses to pay for that feature, they don't want it in that release or anything similar.

Comment: I don't think there's a good general, purely git, solution for this.  In your example let's say you wanted to cut feature 1 instead, and as part of that feature you introduced a refactoring that feature 2 depends on.  If features are truly independent then the answer would be to just not merge them into *devel* branch until customer signs off on the release.

Answer (score 8):

This is indeed a weakness of git-flow. As I see it there exist multiple ways to approach this problem, of which none is perfect.

---

### Feature revert

One way would be to simply [`revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) the *merge* commit from F3.

```
git checkout <release-branch>
git revert --mainline 1 <hash-of-f3-merge-commit>
```

`--mainline 1` (short `-m 1`) tells git to revert the changes of the merge commit relative to it's **first** parent, which is the branch in which the changes were merged in. In our case this would be `develop`.

On the other hand this will lead to problems when you merge the `release` branch back into `develop`, since that will also merge the revert. You will probably have to *re-merge* the feature (F3) into `develop`.

### Alternative release base

This approach bases your release branch on the latest state of `master` instead of `develop`.

```
git checkout -b master <release-branch>
```

From here on you can [`cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) each feature you want to include in the release. Again using the `--mainline` option.

```
git cherry-pick --mainline 1 <hash-of-f1-merge-commit>
git cherry-pick --mainline 1 <hash-of-f2-merge-commit>
```

Alternativly you can [`merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) the feature branches into the release branch instead of `cherry-pick`ing them, which will result in the same outcome but in a more cluttered history (this can be avoided using the `--squash` option followed by a `git commit`, but then you have effectively done a `cherry-pick`).

```
git merge F1
git merge F2
```

The **alternative release base** approach isn't so bad if each release only contains a small subset of the developed features, but is hard to use if you want to release a large number of features.

---

Personally I prefer the latter approach since it results in a cleaner history without *reverts* and duplicated *merge* commits.

Comment: Thanks Zeeker, yes, I also think the alternative release could be better option. At least more clean.
Do you think there are other different workflows apart from gitflow which maybe use an extra predevelop branch? or maybe use short develop branches instead of long ones by merging back to master?

Comment: @Rober Sadly I'm not aware of any other workflow which handles this scenario better. And I'm not sure what you mean by  a `predevelop` branch. You have to remember that *git-flow* isn't the __only true way__ of doing things in git, it's a robust and flexible workflow but there is nothing which stops you to modify it as you see fit.